# Is Stack Overflow an appropriate place for DotNetNuke questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I noticed that there are very few questions on Stack Overflow about [DotNetNuke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DotNetNuke) (DNN). Is this an indicator that DNN has a small Q&A community, or is there a more appropriate place than SO to ask DNN-related programming questions (e.g. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com for [SharePoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SharePoint))?

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15362?tab=ontopic&phase=definition#tab-top

Comment: @Robert-Harvey: Thanks. I may just get involved there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Asking a question about DNN on Stack Overflow is categorically accepted whether they have a stronger community elsewhere or not. In addition, asking about that community, or for other places to seek software support is also categorically accepted.