# Are there special guidelines for moderating exceptionally old questions?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

This question pertains to a very old and fairly insignificant question of my own from nearly a decade ago.

[Is Stack Overflow an appropriate place for DotNetNuke questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59511/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-place-for-dotnetnuke-questions)

The question was recently closed as a duplicate of another question asked roughly three years later.

Mine is a simple question that received a simple and satisfactory answer, and I moved on, grateful for the assistance. I question whether there is value in modifying or closing and merging questions such as these that have surely fallen completely off the SEO radar. While the other question certainly has a detailed and well-authored answer, it actually has nothing specifically to do with DotNetNuke; in fact, DotNetNuke does not appear in the question or answer at all. It really does not address my older question directly.

Now, I don't feel passionate about this particular question, and do not intend to contest anything; however, I do care about StackOverflow, and want to ensure my behavior is aligned with the community the next time I dust off the moderator tools for fun. Was this an appropriate closure? Should questions this old and insignificant even be up for closure as duplicates to much newer--albeit still very old--questions? Are specific questions such as this one about DotNetNuke really duplicates of much more generalized questions?

Comment: I'm unclear whether this post is downvoted for tone, insignificance, or whether it is not well-suited for Meta. Would someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Every non-deleted question is visible and findable, thus eligible for moderation. Then, the age of a dupe/parent question doesn't matter, it only matters if it contains the answer one is looking for. And of course specific questions can be closed as dupe of general question when they provide an answer. If they couldn't we had to answer any topic multiple times, just because the questions differ in slight nuances.

Comment: @Tom Age does matter on some sites, where the rules have changed over time and the general consensus for old questions is "when in doubt, leave it be or take it to meta".

Answer (score 6):

No matter its age, my understanding is that every non-deleted question on every site is still turning up in searches, and rightly so.

Consequently, we want every one of those questions to be unique and to pose a clear question so that it attracts one or more clear answers.

To that end it is important that questions of all ages are moderated to the same high standard, as if they were asked today.

Comment: Thank you Poly, and +1. This addresses the question of whether age matters. Do you also have insights into whether specific questions, such as this one, are considered by the community to be duplicates of more general posts, or newer posts? I understand this is probably true from time to time; though in this case I'm just confused because the favored duplicate doesn't address DotNetNuke at all. I'm not really here to complain--it's not complain-worthy--but I'm genuinely confused as to why this is considered a duplicate, and why after 10 years it warrants closure.

Comment: @kbrimington If you wanted to get a review of the duplicate status, the I would recommend editing that question to reference the duplicate, and to explain clearly why none of the answers address your question.  To me not mentioning DotNetNuke specifically is neither her nor there so if that's the foundation of your case then I think the duplicate is valid.

Comment: Also, don't think of closure as bad, it just means that a question can have no new answers.  If that question was asked today and it is a duplicate, then if the same open question from 10 years ago was spotted today then I think it should be made a duplicate.